# React Higher Order Component forces re-render of wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to understand how to correctly implement this validation behaviour in a higher order component.

===========================================

EDIT: TLDR: Thanks to user @noa-dev 's excellent suggestion I have created a React Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8nLumb74/1/ to show the issue.

## Simply put: Why does my textbox lose focus on editing when wrapped by this HOC?

What am I doing wrong?

The Textbox component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
    changeText(e) {
        if (this.props.validate)
            this.props.validate(e.target.value)
        this.props.update(e.target.value)
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('should only be fired once')
    },
    render() {
        return (<input type="text"
            value={this.props.text}
            onChange={this.changeText} />)
    }
})
```

The Validator component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function (WrappedComponent) {
    const Validation = React.createClass({
        validate(text) {
            console.log('validating', text)
        },
        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                {...this.props}
                validate={this.validate}
                />
            )
        }
    })
    return Validation
}
```

The parent Form component:

```
import React from 'react'
import TextBox from './text-box'
import Validator from './validator'

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return ({text: 'oh hai'})
    },
    update(text) {
        this.setState({text})
    },
    render() {
        const ValidatingTextBox = Validator(TextBox)
        return (<ValidatingTextBox
            text={this.state.text}
            update={this.update} />)
    }
})
```

Comment: I would recommend you looking into Advanced Performance of the react native Docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html. Or simply handle your validation in the same component for the sake of keeping it without any rerenders and only send the finished string to the higher order component to store it.

Comment: definitely a consideration thanks, however currently the app expects any text changes (even before finishing editing this value) to update global state (in this instance held in redux) so that the rest of the app can show you "what it will look like when finished"...

Comment: I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious in my Higher order component setup - i.e. why does React think it needs to tear down the whole input DOM element instead of just updating the value field?

Comment: It doesn't repaint the whole DOM Element, if you use the developer tools of react they provide you a visual highlighting of the BOX in which an update occurs or an rerender - but react as it is is smart enough to just replace the value that needs to be replaced. It's always comparing two virtual DOMs and only replacing stuff that has actually changed. But since the value of the field is being changed you will always see a highlight around your input component. I just read that the user loses focus on the Field - that shouldn't happen... Can you prepare a react fiddle so I can test it?

Comment: Sure, thanks...
1. A working example without the HOC and focus isn't lost: https://jsfiddle.net/qkg328n2/

Comment: and 2. A failing example WITH the HOC and focus IS lost: https://jsfiddle.net/8nLumb74/1/ (apologies this was meant to be in the comment above and I hit enter too soon!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the `render` method of the `Form` component, you are creating a new `ValidatingTextBox` every time:

```
    render() {
        const ValidatingTextBox = Validator(TextBox)
        return (<ValidatingTextBox
            text={this.state.text}
            update={this.update} />)
    }
```

Instead, you should make the component and then use it so the instance gets maintained. A possible `Form` component would look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import TextBox from './text-box'
import Validator from './validator'

const ValidatingTextBox = Validator(TextBox) 

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return ({text: 'oh hai'})
    },
    update(text) {
        this.setState({text})
    },
    render() {
        return (<ValidatingTextBox
            text={this.state.text}
            update={this.update} />)
    }
})
```

Comment: so the only problem was that my composition was inside my render method? Damn I'm so stupid - thanks LOADS Davin!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I need to choose one component based on a prop.

`switch (type) {
case "a":
componentToBeRendered = FormA;
break;
case "b":
componentToBeRendered = FormB;
break;
}
const FinalComponent = HOC(componentToBeRendered, propsObject);
`

So, the form is re-rendering as soon as I type a character in input field.