# How to render a HOC in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm trying to render a HOC with react but I cannot figure it out how to make it works.
So I have one HOC that is working perfect with react-navigation.
My idea is to show a component that the render wraps a HOC. I am trying to do sth like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={viewStyle}>
        {CheckLogin(Login)}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

this CheckLogin is the HOC and Login is the component itself. The result is that React is not complaining but is in blank. Any idea how to render a HOC invoking the Component itself??

Comment: `{CheckLogin}` means you're interpretting JS.  If you want the component, you need `<CheckLogin />`.  Not sure that's you're whole issue, but it's a start?

Comment: Maybe I'm just dense but what's an HOC?

Comment: A hoc = high order components. @jmargolisvt  the problem is that i have to pass props and i do not know how

Comment: What props do you need to pass to your `Login` component? Passing props to another component is as simple as `<Login user="name"/>`. Is there something special that `CheckLogin()` is supposed to do?

Comment: The point is that CheckLogin contains some methods that will be rendered on the component that is passed( Login). Then i am using react navigation, so i should send this.props.navigation to the CheckLogin component

Comment: Can you post how your HOC looks? It would help us since there's more than one way to make a HOC :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are just calling the HOC as a function inside the JSX, instead you need to use `</>` in order to render it.

```
// Apply your HOC
const EnhancedComponent = CheckLogin(Login);

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {      
    return (
      <View style={viewStyle}>
        <EnhancedComponent  />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That works! Really thank you @Crysfel. My problem is that I was trying to render it directly on the return. That helped a lot and it lets me apply the power of HOC.

Comment: @Crysfel, Don't Use HOCs Inside the render Method.

Calling the HOC in render would case the component to remount on every render. [Documented here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/044015760883d03f060301a15beef17909abbf71/docs/docs/higher-order-components.md#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method) and also [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120494/react-higher-order-component-forces-re-render-of-wrapped-component)